# Superset charts customization (and column names)

Tags: apache-superset

Would like to know if I understand the following correctly:

- In order to customize charts we can use CSS templates
- with JSON I can only work with data and connection (so if I want to customize something it's only with CSS)
- If I want custom charts I should dive in echarts/preset/custom viz via npm yo etc.

Can I do a dynamic column name based on parameter (like in tableau for example) (so if I choose "%" column name be like "%_of_money" and "number" => "number_of_money")?

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic columns i think you could  create the columns as metrics. Refer to tutorial on this blog.
https://preset.io/blog/understanding-superset-semantic-layer/